# Dask Dataframe- read_sql_table - where condition

Tags: dask

I need to retrieve only rows where record_status is 'New' into a Dask Dataframe.

currently I am using below and creating pandas Dataframe as below

```
cnx = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost/sshema',
    echo=False)
df_party = pd.read_sql('select  first_name, last_name from party where record_status = \'New\'', con=cnx)
```

I want to do the same and create Dask Dataframe. Below is what I tried and is working. How can I add where condition to this to only retrieve rows with  record_status 'New'

```
ddf_party = dd.read_sql_table('party','mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost/schema',
                            index_col='create_date', columns = ['first_name', 'last_name'])
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `table` argument of `dask.dataframe.read_sql_table` supports SQLAlchemy expressions -- it ain't pretty though:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

sqluri = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost/schema"
engine = sa.create_engine(sqluri)

sa_meta = sa.MetaData()
sa_table = sa.Table("party", sa_meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
sa_query = sa.select([sa_table]).where(sa_table.c.record_status == "New")
sa_columns = [sa_table.c.first_name, sa_table.c.last_name]

ddf_party = dd.read_sql_table(sa_query, sqluri, index_col="create_date", columns=sa_columns)
```

Comment: Tried your code, getting error "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias". Not sure but looks like the alias is not getting set correctly for the index_col column in the SQL.

Comment: sa_query = sa.select([sa_table]).where(sa_table.c.record_status == "New").alias('foo').  this should work.